# How to deploy an etcd cluster on a Kubernetes cluster with a previous etcd service

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I have been reading for several days about how to deploy a Kubernetes cluster from scratch. It's all ok until it comes to etcd.

I want to deploy the etcd nodes inside the Kubernetes cluster. It looks there are many options, like etcd-operator (https://github.com/coreos/etcd-operator).

But, to my knowledge, a StatefulSet or a ReplicaSet makes use of a etcd.

So, what is the right way to deploy such a cluster?

My first thought: start with a single member etcd, either as a pod or a local service in the master node and, when the Kubernetes cluster is up, deploy the etcd StatefulSet and *move/change/migate* the initial etcd to the new cluster.

The last part sounds weird to me: "and *move/change/migate* the initial etcd to the new cluster."

Am I wrong with this approach?

I don't find useful information on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has 3 components: master components, node components and addons.

**Master components**

- kube-apiserver
- etcd
- kube-scheduler
- kube-controller-manager/cloud-controller-manager

**Node components**

- kubelet
- kube-proxy
- Container Runtime

While implementing Kubernetes yu have to implement etcd as part of it. If it is multi node architecture you can use independent node or along with master node as per your requirement. You can find more details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/). If you are looking for step by step guide follow [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/) document if you need multi node architecture. If you need single node Kubernetes go for minikube.

Comment: Yes. I know the Kubernetes architecture, and I read in depth these links when I started with Kubernetes. However, none of them provides an answer to my question. When you say "you have to implement etcd as *part of it*", *part of it* means Kubernetes depends on an etcd service to work, but this service can be implemented in several ways: as local machine service, as a container, as an external dedicated cluster, ... I just want my cluster be self-contained, no matter the number of nodes. So I can have a 2-node cluster with a 3-member etcd assigned to nodes by the Kubernetes scheduler.